# Submit a form with jquery and receive json to process

Tags: jquery, json

I would like to submit a form to a Python script that processes the form data and return json which should be processed on the form again.

I managed to submit the whole form and pass the form data to the Python script but I don't get the json result out of it.

Here is how my html looks like:

### html form

```
<div id="result"></div>    
<form id="myform" action="processForm.py">  
Title:  <input type="text" name="title"  id="title"  placeholder="Enter title" />
Author: <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Enter author" />
<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Javascript

```
// wait for the DOM to be loaded 
$(document).ready(function() { 
//hang on event of form with id=myform
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
//prevent Default functionality - stay at the form
e.preventDefault();
//get the action-url of the form
var actionurl = e.currentTarget.action;        
//do your own request an handle the results
$.ajax({
    url: actionurl,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $("#myform").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        $("result").html(
          "Message: " + data["message"]
        );       
    }
});
return false;
});
});
```

The Python script only returns this json object:

```
{'message':'Hello world.'}
```

When I hit the submit button the form data is sent to the Python script properly and I want to display the json result within the  element.
The problem is, that the div elements stays empty when I hit the submit button - and I don't know, what's wrong.

I am pretty new to jQuery so I am wondering if someone could help me here.

Comment: Replace $("result") with $("#result")

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew, it bust be something very simple... ;-)